# Muting “replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers” WARNing in Spark Streaming while in Local Mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Is there a way to mute “replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers” WARNing in Spark Streaming while running in Local Mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console
```

to

```
log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console
```

in log4j.properties

Answer (score 0):

Although, this is an old question with already an expected answer which works, It'll suppress all the log4j logs except *ERROR*.

The more precise way of only suppressing the storage logs would be to set the logger for `org.apache.spark.storage` to *ERROR*.

```
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark.storage").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
```

Or in case of Log4J configuration:

```
log4j.org.apache.spark.storage=ERROR, consoleAppender
```